# 80's/90's TV movie or miniseries about an artificial kid delivered in a 50 gallon drum

Tags: story-identification, tv

I saw it in the late 80's or early 90's; I'm pretty sure it was a miniseries. There was some company or governmental organization behind the manufacture of this kid, probably many such kids (I don't recall), and the child was being transported in a drum much like one of these:

[image: Image of oil drums]

I feel like the main child somehow erroneously wound up with a family and the company wanted him back.

Comment: I remember a kid's book in the early 80s with that premise; a woman liked ordering random things from catalogues and accidentally ordered a child in a can.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - that sounds close enough, based on my scant memory, that perhaps the movie/miniseries was based on that book.  I seem to remember that they were surprised to see the child wind up on their doorstep.

Comment: Wait, are you saying that that ISN'T where babies come from?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may be thinking of the TV movie named *Konrad* released by Wonderworks in 1985.

> Konrad is a perfect instant child "born" in a factory at age 8. Due to a mistake in the factory's computer, Konrad is delivered to Bertie Bartolotti, a woman whose life and appearance are in a constant state of disarray. Konrad arrives looking like a gremlin, but when Bertie pours a nutrient solution over his head he changes into a fully-developed, perfect 8-year-old child. The factory realizes a mistake was made, and recalls Konrad, but he does not want to leave his new family and friends.
>
> <sub>[IMDb, *Konrad*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0167240/)</sub>

[image: Konrad cover]

[image: Konrad back]

Comment: Which is a remake of the German film [Conrad, the Factory-Made Boy](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084220/), which is based on the book by the same name by Christine Nostlinger, which is the one I was remembering :)

Comment: Watched the first 5 minutes on YouTube - that's the one, thanks, you're awesome!

Comment: For some reason I'd assumed you meant [D.A.R.Y.L.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D.A.R.Y.L.). How many movies fit this description?