# '80s kids show where orphaned children are kidnapped and trapped in cans with plastic lids

Tags: story-identification, tv

I vaguely remember a TV show that kinda reminded me of a style like *Punky Brewster*, where these orphaned children kept getting taken away or kidnapped by scientists or something like that, in cans that had plastic lids like Pringles cans. Anyone know which show I’m thinking of?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: What happened when they were canned? Were they placed in them dead, or could they be revived afterwards?

Answer (score 2):

There was a children's book, adapted into an after-school movie called Conrad (The factory-made boy) by Christine Nostlinger that features a child who arrives (by mistake) to a woman, packed in a can, partially dehydrated.

The process isn't quite explained, but the manufacturer tries to retrieve the boy, a result he makes clear he doesn't want.

Full movie -

Comment: If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/138244/23243

Comment: Interestingly, there was an original 1983 German made-for-TV movie called [Conrad: The Factory-Made Boy](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0167240/) and a 1985 US remake called just [Konrad](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084220). You've referenced the former, but linked the latter

Comment: *Konrad* was immediately what the imagery in the question reminded me of.

Answer (score 1):

The date's slightly off (1991), and the children weren't orphans, but otherwise the first episode of "Eerie, Indiana", ["ForeverWare"](https://imdb.com/title/tt0569394/), sounds rather like this.

> Marshall and his family are welcomed to their new home town by Betty Wilson  who encourages Marshall's mom to buy ForeverWare - a special type of plastic container guaranteed to keep anything fresh forever. And when they say it keeps anything fresh they really do mean anything,

> including Mrs Wilson's twin sons who have been sealed in giant ForeverWare boxes every night for 30 years to prevent them from aging! It's up to Marshall and Simon to help the twins finally get out of the 7th grade.